# How to identify the web-element for a Text Box using Selenium for the dynamically changing ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a input text box having id property and the HTML for it as shown below

```
username:<input type="text" id="1234"><br>
```

Id property is dynamically changing. when the page loads next time.

```
Username:<input type="text" id="5678"><br>
```

and the value continuously changing.

how to write the XPath for the above scenario.

Here we have only one ID property no other properties are available. I know we can use contains,starts-with or write absolute XPath helps in other cases.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Share your HTML code please. With parents.

Comment: Will CSS locators work? Can you ask developers to add a name?

Comment: Seeing the HTML code would help tremendously, as Sagar007 mentioned above, but barring that, this might work (untested): `//*[contains(text(),'Username:')]/input`

Answer (score 2):

How I handle dynamic IDs:

1. Inspect the element using Chrome's DevTools
2. Edit the element and remove the `id="..."` attribute
3. Right-click the element
4. Select `"Copy" > "Copy selector"` (or you could do XPath if you really want)

You now have a selector that doesn't use the ID attribute, but most likely it's DOM position. Something like `"body > div:nth-child(1) > input"` instead of `"#1234".`

---

2020 UPDATE: I don't do this anymore and do what Bill said which is `//*[contains(text(),'Username')]/input`. That translates to:

- `//` anywhere in the DOM
- `*` any tagName
- `[contains(text(),'Username')]` where the text value contains 'Username'
- `/input` the following <input>

Comment: @kirbycope...thank you!  Save a lot of time for this beginner

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[text()='Username']"));
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer, please? I don't see how your xpath will locate the element based on the information in the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18576)

Comment: @TESTasy Note that an incorrect answer is still an answer.

Comment: In that sense every post on a question is an answer (Some correct others incorrect) including, link only answers, thank you posts, spam and anything else! BUT whatever!

Answer (score 1):

In such case I talk to a developer to introduce a fixed way to locate an element, e.g., by `name` attribute:

```
Username: <input type="text" id="5678" name="username"><br>
```

Comment: or appending the random part of an id to a fixed one like userinput+5678. No need to introduce an entirely new tag.

Comment: @Leon. New tag doesn't cost much and using new tag will make locators clear, e.g. By.name("username").

Comment: Of course, didnt say it cost something but no need to clutter up code there either. The same line that introduces the random value could be made to include a fixed part as well, no need for new lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

> Xpath provide `following-sibling` functionality with text :

**Solution :**

First we identify text element and then find following sibling.

**Try this xpath :**

```
//*[contains(.,'Username')]//following-sibling::input
```

*Note : Here change initial `*` with parent of your input element like `div` or `form`.*